# Swift Classes and Functions

Tags: swift

I am taking a course on swift and I had to write a code for this senario and I have no idea why my function is not working. I am getting extremely irritated.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa

// create class

class State
{
    var population: Double?
    var capital: String?
    var name: String?
    var growthRate: Double?
    var nextYearPopulation: Double?
    var neighbors: [State]


// initialize vars
    init(population: Double?, capital: String?, name: String?, growthRate: Double?, neighbors: [State])
    {
        self.population = population
        self.capital = capital
        self.name = name
        self.growthRate = growthRate
        self.neighbors = neighbors
    }

    var Texas = State(population: 1000000, capital: "Austin", name: "Texas", growthRate: 0.012, neighbors: [])

    var Oklahoma = State(population: 3000000, capital: "Oklahoma City", name: "Oklahoma", growthRate: 0.01, neighbors: [])

    var NewMexico = State(population: 1000000, capital: "Santa Fe", name: "New Mexico", growthRate: 0.02, neighbors: [])

    var NewYork = State(population: 25000000, capital: "New York City", name: "New York", growthRate: 0.1, neighbors: [])

    var Virginia = State(population: 15000000, capital: "Richmond", name: "Virginia", growthRate: 0.03, neighbors: [])

    var Florida = State(population: 20000000, capital: "Tallahassee", name: "Florida", growthRate: 0.07, neighbors: [])

    //functions

    func populationAfter()
    {
        nextYearPopulation = self.growthRate! * self.population!
        print("The projected population for ", self.name, "is ", nextYearPopulation)
    }

    Texas.populationAfter()


}
```

Comment: Why does it not work? Does it crash, or set your computer on fire maybe?

Comment: my populationAfter() function wont work.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What do you expect to get from your function and what do you get instead?

Comment: nothing happens. it should calculate and print the expected population

Comment: You should move your states and your call to `Texas.populationAfter()` outside of your class definition.

Comment: When I do that I get this error -> Playground execution failed: /var/folders/n0/5r1gpwtx2p14n3_hwb7fgl7w0000gp/T/./lldb/16756/playground22.swift:50:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'Texas'
Texas.populationAfter()
^~~~~

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: ^^^^ That error is the most important thing of your question, btw, keep in mind that whenever you are looking for answers.

Comment: On an unrelated note, is it possible to have a state with no name, population, capital, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your state `var`s and call to `Texas.populationAfter()` to after your class definition.  It doesn't make sense for `State` to have properties called `Texas`, `Oklahoma`, etc., but that is what your code is doing.  The call to `Texas.populationAfter()` in your code is completely illegal because code needs to be inside of a function declaration.

By moving the creation of the states outside of the `State` class, you are then creating variables using the `State` class definition, and then you can call the `populationAfter()` method on the `State` instance called `Texas`.

Note, it is a recommended practice in Swift to use strings starting with lowercase letters for vars and properties, and Strings starting with uppercase letters for class and struct types.

Note that your `populationAfter` function was just calculating the population growth.  To get the new updated population, multiply by `1 + self.growthRate!` instead.

```
class State
{
    var population: Double?
    var capital: String?
    var name: String?
    var growthRate: Double?
    var nextYearPopulation: Double?
    var neighbors: [State]

    // initialize vars
    init(population: Double?, capital: String?, name: String?, growthRate: Double?, neighbors: [State])
    {
        self.population = population
        self.capital = capital
        self.name = name
        self.growthRate = growthRate
        self.neighbors = neighbors
    }

    //functions

    func populationAfter()
    {
        nextYearPopulation = (1 + self.growthRate!) * self.population!
        print("The projected population for ", self.name!, "is ", nextYearPopulation!)
    }
}

var Texas = State(population: 1000000, capital: "Austin", name: "Texas", growthRate: 0.012, neighbors: [])

var Oklahoma = State(population: 3000000, capital: "Oklahoma City", name: "Oklahoma", growthRate: 0.01, neighbors: [])

var NewMexico = State(population: 1000000, capital: "Santa Fe", name: "New Mexico", growthRate: 0.02, neighbors: [])

var NewYork = State(population: 25000000, capital: "New York City", name: "New York", growthRate: 0.1, neighbors: [])

var Virginia = State(population: 15000000, capital: "Richmond", name: "Virginia", growthRate: 0.03, neighbors: [])

var Florida = State(population: 20000000, capital: "Tallahassee", name: "Florida", growthRate: 0.07, neighbors: [])

Texas.populationAfter()
```

Comment: OHHHH so its about the sequence of placement in the program! Thank you so much!

Comment: Not _sequence_ but _containment_. Curly braces have a meaning. Being inside them is very different from being outside them.

Comment: The problem was that the function call was inside a class declaration block, and in a declaration block you can only declare stuff, you can't execute anything.

Comment: I would also add that you don't *need* to declare the vars outside the class declaration, you can keep them in there but you'll have to call them like this `State.Texas`

Comment: Unless it is valid to have a State without a capital, a name, or a growthRate, I would suggest that you avoid using optional variables here.  They just complicate things because you have to unwrap them.  Using force unwrapping `!` will lead to crashes when the variables are `nil`.

Comment: Ok so the last part I am having trouble with! I have to make a function to tell if a states neighbor is true or false. I can't seem to find what is wrong with my isNeighbor function.

Comment: Did you update the `neighbors` properties of your states so that they would know who their neighbors are?  Update your question and post your `isNeighbor` function.